# Session management across subdomain and root domain?

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, express

So here is the situation:

I have api.localhost and localhost.

api.localhost - REST API for DB access and session management.

localhost - Simple web application relying on api.localhost.

Now my question is:
1. How to set cookies such that cookies set by api.localhost are accessible to localhost also. (i am using passport and MongoStore for session management)

1. When cookies are received at localhost, i make a http request to api.localhost to check their authenticity. How do i send cookies i received with that request?

PS. - Trust me I tried very hard to explain the problem in simplest way.

Comment: Does localhost web application connect to api.localhost server-side or from browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Database. In clearly say, you have to store session in database. If your domain and all your sub-domains read single database, then user can access same session from different domain.

By Default, HTTP client(Browser) is not allowed to read cookie from cross domain. So you have to explicitly set domain information in your cookie.

```
Let me explain clear,
```

Let us assume, You have a main domain namely `mymaindomain.com` and you have some sub domains likely `subdomain1.mymaindomain.com, subdomain2.mymaindomain.com, subdomain3.mymaindomain.com, and more`

Now A user is logged in your main domain `mymaindomain.com`. And your application set session cookie to identify user. By default Browser check host to send cookie with request. In your case, If user moves to sub-domain `subdomain1.mymaindomain.com`, then browser simply try to create new session.

To force the browser, send cookie from `mymaindomain.com`, you have to set "Domain" attribute of cookie. In this case, the explicit domain attribute is exactly `mymaindomain.com`. Now assume, user moves to `subdomain1.mymaindomain.com` then browser automatically send session-cookie which is set by `mymaindomain.com`.

This is happen, because here browser match highlighted part on following sub-domain `subdomain1.`**mymaindomain.com**.

So that your application get same session-cookie or user session and rest of the work should be take care of back-end application. Same kind of domain restriction happen in your back-end as well. If you want to support browser request for sub-domain, your sub-domain app should read session information from database which is common to `mymaindomain.com` and other sub-domains like `subdomain2.mymaindomain.com, subdomain3.mymaindomain.com, and more`

**Note: This will not work if your domain is entirely change, I mean the browser wont send session-cookie, if your hosting domains are entirely changed.**